# Drawing an ellipse in THREE.js

Tags: html5-canvas, three.js

I'm trying to draw a 3D ellipse with THREE.js.

I noticed in the dev version (r50-dev), `EllipseCurve` ([extras/core/Curve.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/extras/core/Curve.js)) and `path.ellipse` ([extras/core/Path.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/extras/core/Path.js)) have been added.

Unfortunately, I am new to THREE.js and although I can do basic things, I haven't been able to find a tutorial on Curve, much less a tutorial on the still-in-developement EllipseCurve.

I also understand I can do this with multiple bezier curves.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [this example](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html) as reference and lookng at the [EllipseCurve](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/extras/core/Curve.js#L439) code.

Comment: I tried getting the points in the EllipseCurve and using createPointsGeoemtry on a shape, but how do I get the object to curve smoothly instead of being a hexagon?  I was able to createPointsGeometry of an elliptical shape made up of bezierCurves, not using the EllipseCurve object.

Comment: Can you share a picture of that?

Comment: No need, I realized my problem was that I was passing a too low parameter to ellipse.getPoints().  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A more recent (R149) example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> three.js ellipse </title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.149.0/three.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas width='1000' height='750'></canvas>
    <script>
  'use strict';
  let canvas, w, h, renderer, scene, camera;
  let geometry, material, points, lines, mesh, curve;
  canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
  w = canvas.clientWidth;
  h = canvas.clientHeight;
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas:canvas } );
  renderer.setSize(w, h);
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(27, w / h, 1, 2000);
  camera.position.z = 1000;

  // from https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/curves/EllipseCurve
  material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
  curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve( 0,0, 200, 150); // define curve
  points = curve.getPoints( 50 );                 // an array of { 'x':x, 'y':y } from curve
  geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
  lines = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
  scene.add( lines );

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```