# Three.js draw ellipse from point list

Tags: javascript, three.js

I’m coding a solar system model with Three.js. I have a function that calculates the planet position given the day, however I’m not able to draw the correct orbit of the planet (elliptic) starting from a list of points obtained from that function.I googled a lot but I haven’t found an example, how can I do this?

EDIT: these are my functions, one for drawing the ellipse and one for moving the planets

```
function drawOrbitTest(orbit) {

  var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });

  var points = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < orbit.orbitPeriod; i += 7) {
    //basically what i'm trying to do here is calculating the position of the planet 
    //with an increment of one week for cycle
    if (orbit.orbitPeriod - i <= 7) {
      var endPoint = calcPosition(orbit, Date.now() + 86400 * 1000 * orbit.orbitPeriod);
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(endPoint.x * AU, endPoint.y * AU, endPoint.z * AU));
      break;
    } else {
      var middlePoint = calcPosition(orbit, Date.now() + 86400 * 1000 * i);
      points.push(new THREE.Vector3(middlePoint.x * AU, middlePoint.y * AU, middlePoint.z * AU));
    }
  }

  var shape = new THREE.Shape(points);
  var geomShape = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry(shape);
  var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial(orbit.color);
  var ellipse = new THREE.Line(geomShape, material);
  scene.add(ellipse);
}
```

and

```
function rotateOnEllipse(obj, date) {
  var res = calcPosition(obj.orbit, date);
  obj.mesh.position.x = res.x * AU;
  obj.mesh.position.y = res.y * AU;
  obj.mesh.position.z = res.z * AU;
}
```

EDIT 2: I followed @prisoner849 suggestion, now it works, the planets move on their orbits. However, the orbit now is more like a "ring" than an ellipse; why is it drawn like that?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851276/three-js-ellipse) out

Comment: @jscastro this one uses EllipseCurve, i need to build the orbit connecting the points because due to some approximations it may be not a perfect ellipse. If I use EllipseCurve the movement of the planet and the orbit don’t coincide

Comment: It’s hard to know if you didn’t specify that. If your ellipse does not correspond with a formula-based Ellipse, why don’t you build a THREE.Shape that has a constructor that accepts a list of Vector3 points?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, in my head "draw an ellipse from points" already implied that but I acknowledge that I should have specified that. However, I did like you suggested but the planets are still moving outside the orbit. I've added code snippets

Comment: `var ellipse = new THREE.Line(new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points), material);`, without additional `Shape` and `ShapeBufferGeometry`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the rendering of the line was caused by a bug in the function

```js
calcPosition(orbit,date)
```

(it was giving back slightly different points if called with date and date+orbitPeriod).

@prisoner849's suggestion worked for me